# Maximum box gap

Tags: code-golf

**Task**

You have a row of numbered boxes, with some filled with items and some empty. Your job is to output the number of boxes from the first to the last box, inclusive, minus the number of boxes of the largest gap between two filled boxes.

**Rules**

Your program should handle up to 1000 boxes. Score = size of program in bytes. -50 if you don't use a built-in sorting functionality. -150 if you program in assembly :D All cases will have at least one gap.

Input is a list of n-th boxes that are filled. Standard loop-holes aren't allowed.

**Sample Input**

```
9, 5, 4, 2
```

Functions with a list as input are fine.

**Sample Output**

```
5
```

This is the number of boxes between the 2nd and 9th box, inclusive, subtracted by the number of boxes of the gap between the 5th and 9th box (8 - 3 = 5)

Comment: @MartinBüttner I've edited it so hopefully it's clearer.

Comment: @MartinBüttner Functions are okay.

Comment: Can I assume input to be like `[9 5 4 2]` ?

Comment: 1. Are the box numbers always in descending order? At least one answer seems to assume this. 2. Will the box numbers always be positive integers?

Comment: @Dennis No, and the boxes are numbered starting from 1.

Comment: So, if I understood correctly, `9 4 5 2`, `9 4 2 5` and all other permutations of `9 5 4 2` should all yield 5. Correct?

Comment: @Dennis Not if the maximum difference between two adjacent numbers is larger/smaller than before.

Comment: @Shujal: The way Martin, Optimizer and I interpreted the question, *first* and *last* box refer to the boxes with the lowest and highest number, and *gaps* also refers to the filled boxes in their natural order rather than their order in the array.

Comment: @Dennis Ok, now I get it... I was confused because the boxes were next to each other in the array and no other examples were given. I updated my answer to match the requirements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## CJam, <s>-19</s> <s>-22</s> -23 (27 bytes - 50 bonus)

```
Vq~_:+,\&_(+]z{~-~:Xe>}/X+z
```

[Try it online.](http://cjam.aditsu.net/)

#### Example run

```
$ cjam box-gap.cjam <<< '[9 5 4 2]'; echo
5
```

#### How it works

```
V                              " V := 0                                          ";
 q~                            " Q := eval(input))                               ";
   _:+,                        " S := range(sum(Q))                              ";
       \&                      " T := S ∩ T          # Preserves the order of S. ";
         _(+                   " U := T[1:] + [T[0]]                             ";
            ]z                 " Z := zip(T, U)                                  ";
              {       }/       " for (X,Y) ∊ Z:                                  ";
               :-~:Me>         "   V := max(V, M := ~(X - Y))                    ";
                        M+z    " R := abs(V + M)                                 ";
```

Answer (score 5):

### CJam, -8 (<s>43</s> 42 bytes - 50 bonus)

```
l~:A{e>}*A{e<}*-)A{_A\-f{-z}{e<}*}%{e>}*(-
```

Using tips by @Dennis!

[Try it online here](http://cjam.aditsu.net/)

Input is like:

```
[9 5 4 2]
```

Comment: The bug with folding `e<` and `e>` is really annoying, isn't it? ;)

Comment: Yeah, 9 extra characters :(

Comment: You can use `f{-z}` instead of `\f-{z}%`. (I was going to suggest `:z`, but that doesn't seem to work either.)

Comment: Yeah, too many non : supported operations :(

Comment: Sadly. You don't need the ``\`` before `f`.

Comment: Nice! I wished these things were more properly documented..

Answer (score 4):

### Mathematica, 44 bytes

```
f=Max@#-Min@#-Max[RotateLeft[l=Sort@#]-l]+2&
```

Defines a function that takes one argument in form of a list `{9, 5, 4, 2}`.

Comment: Wow, you're fast. What does purpose does `RotateLeft` have?

Comment: @qwr Well, it rotates the array to the left ^^. So `{2,4,5,9}` becomes `{4,5,9,2}`. Subtracting the original (sorted) list, gives me all gaps (plus one), i.e. `{2,1,4,-7}`. The last element is of course useless, but since it's always negative it doesn't matter for `Max`.

Answer (score 1):

### APL (Dyalog 14) (34 - 50 = -16)

```
{⎕ML←3⋄(1+V-⌊/⍵)-⌈/≢¨⊂⍨~⍵∊⍨⍳V←⌈/⍵}
```

This is a function that takes a list.

Or, for the same amount of characters:

```
⎕ML←3⋄(1+V-⌊/B)-⌈/≢¨⊂⍨~B∊⍨⍳V←⌈/B←⎕
```

This reads the list from the keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

### Python 2 - 54 (<s>117</s>104-50)

```py
x=input()
M=max(x)-min(x)+1
X=['1']*M
for i in x:X[i-min(x)]='0'
print M-len(max("".join(X).split('0')))
```

A program that pretends that the buckets are real, then awkwardly splits them into groups. Takes input like `9,5,4,2`.